# Cómo puedo hacer para que el usuario escriba más de 1valor en 1 textbox y que estos se almacenen en 1 array con un formulario C++/CLR en Visual Studio

Tags: c++, array, visual-studio, textbox, código-fuente

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en un formulario C++/CLR en Visual Studio, y lo que hace es calcular el área de un triángulo irregular con la fórmula del área de Gauss.

Aquí dejo el link de la fórmula del área de Gauss: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_del_%C3%A1rea_de_Gauss

Lo que quiero es que el usuario introduzca las coordenadas en un mismo textbox, y que un array guarde todos los valores, pero no sé cómo hacer para que el usuario pueda introducir más de un valor en un mismo textbox y que estos valores después se almacenen en un array. Y tampoco sé cómo crear un array en este tipo de formulario. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Es para un proyecto del instituto.

Comment: Podría tener algún boceto del código que intenté hacer, o un mínimo del código que programé

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Lo siento, no podemos ayudarte sin ver tu código. Por cierto, por qué no usas C# para programar con Windows Forms?